# android display images (different screen resolutions) on ImageView from json data

Tags: android, json, imageview, android-screen-support, android-screen

I am getting json data. In that json I have a array of images urls for different screen resolutions for one image like this

```
"images": {
                "full_url": "http://******/assets/tmp/",
                "ldpi": "http://******/assets/tmp/ldpi/****.png",
                "mdpi": "http://******/assets/tmp/mdpi/****.png",
                "hdpi": "http://******/assets/tmp/hdpi/****.png",
                "xdpi": "http://******/assets/tmp/xdpi/****.png"
            }
```

i want to display this image dependent on screen size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like below,

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

//DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW - LDPI(120)
//DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM - MDPI(160)
//DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH - HDPI(240)
//DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH - XHDPI(320)
//DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH - XXHDPI(480)
//DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH - XXXHDPI(640)
```

based on the density you can add the image, ref [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) too.

Ex ;

```
if(density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
    // Use mdpi image in your JSON
} else if(density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {
    // use xdpi image in your JSON
} else if(density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
    // use xdpi image in your JSON
} else {
    // use full image
}
```

Comment: I want to know how to decide which image url to use?

Comment: added example have a look